# how to resolve this error:Read: Data overflow/conversion error

Tags: informatica, data-quality

how to resolve this error:Read: Data overflow/conversion error for [some field] .I am getting this error after running the mapping in informatica data quality 9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below steps:

1) Check for the columns which may have date values in them. If the datatypes are not compatible in any of the transformations, error may come.

2) Always debug or run the data viewer for each of the transformation before you run the IDQ mapping. It will give you an overview of the data and issues if any.